# Using Libraries in Salesforce Lightning

Tags: lightning, libraries

We used Libraries a lot in salesforce classic and have now moved to salesforce lightning. Here we have files with libraries as a subsection but with very limited functionality in comparison to classic.

I want to do 1 of 2 things:

1 - Be able to create a lightning page called libraries with all the functionality you have in classic - e.g. popular tabs, top content etc

2 - Be able to reference either a visualforce or lightning page that just opens up the classic view of libraries when you click on the tab

Any ideas would be greatly helpful - surely lots of people must have run into this same issue in the transition

Thanks

Comment: You mean these https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=content_workspace_create.htm&type=0 right?

Comment: Yes the standard libraries - these are available in an intuitive view in classic but just a list view in lightning